# log4j config when testing to show only Errors

Tags: java, spring, log4j, eclipselink, dbunit

I have a Spring application, where I use eclipselink and dbunit for my tests I've created this **log4j.xml** file on /src/test/resources/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
        xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                    value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

But when i run the tests I see a lot of messages in the console, not only the error ones:

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.pastis.services.config.TestConfig
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [ERROR].
log4j: root level set to ERROR
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
[EL Fine]: 2020-09-30 17:08:19.045--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Configured server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.wls.WebLogicPlatform
[EL Config]: 2020-09-30 17:08:19.298--ServerSession(142103421)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class com.pastis.FactureCommentType] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: 2020-09-30 17:08:19.335--ServerSession(142103421)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The target entity (reference) class for the one to many mapping element [field factureComments] is being defaulted to: class com.pastis.mode                           
[EL Config]: 2020-09-30 17:08:19.336--ServerSession(142103421)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class com.pastis.model.inscriptions.Institution] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: 2020-09-30 17:08:19.336--ServerSession(142103421)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The target entity (reference) class for the one to many mapping element [field personneAffectations] is being defaulted to: class eu.europa.ec.oi
[EL Fine]: 2020-09-30 17:08:58.808--ServerSession(142103421)--Connection(1923962747)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT COUNT(EXERCICE_ID) FROM EXERCICE
```

this is my `/src/test/java/META-INF/persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="pastis-server-services">
      <properties>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="false"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="OFF" />
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="OFF" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and in my maven pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <eclipselink.showSql>false</eclipselink.showSql>
    <eclipselink.logging.level>OFF</eclipselink.logging.level>
    <eclipselink.logging.level.sql>OFF</eclipselink.logging.level.sql>
</properties>
```

Comment: The wiki: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging describes logging in EclipseLink. I this case, it seems you are on Weblogic server, and if using container managed persistence, it is likely injecting its own logger into the persistence unit - you would need to use the WebLogic console to change the logging settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log level configuration is included in the definition of the persistence unit in the persistence.xml ,

add this:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="OFF" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="OFF" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The wiki: wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging describes logging in EclipseLink. I this case, it seems you are on Weblogic server (as determined by the Configured server platform WebLogicPlatform log message), and if using container managed persistence, it is likely injecting its own logger into the persistence unit - you would need to use the WebLogic console to change the logging settings.

You can prevent this by adding:

```
 <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>
```

To the persistence.xml, which will have EclipseLink use its own logging, which will use the settings you have already configured.